# How do I make a constexpr swap function?

Tags: c++, swap, constexpr, string-view

I'm making my own String View class for learning purposes, and I'm trying to make it 100% constexpr.

To test it, I have a member function that returns an hash value. I then construct my string view in a switch statement and call that same member function, if it passes, that member function has fullfiled its purpose.

To learn, I'm using / reading / comparing my implementation with Visual Studio 2017 latest update `std::string_view`, however, I've noticed that, despite `swap` being marked as `constexpr`, it does not work, nor in Visual Studio, nor in g++.

This is the piece of code that does not work:

```
constexpr Ali::String::View hello("hello");
constexpr Ali::String::View world("world");
// My implementation fails here!
hello.swap(world);
cout << hello << " " << world << endl;    

// Visual Studio implementation fails here!
// std::string_view with char const * is not constexpr because of the length
constexpr std::string_view hello("hello");
constexpr std::string_view world("world");
hello.swap(world);
cout << hello << " " << world << endl;
```

And this is Visual Studio implementation of if:

```
constexpr void swap(basic_string_view& _Other) _NOEXCEPT
        {   // swap contents
        const basic_string_view _Tmp{_Other};   // note: std::swap is not constexpr
        _Other = *this;
        *this = _Tmp;
        }
```

This one is from my class and it's similar to the one from Visual Studio.

```
constexpr void swap(View & input) noexcept {
    View const data(input);
    input = *this;
    *this = data;
}
```

All constructors and assignments are marked as constexpr.

Both Visual Studio and g++ give me similar errors.

```
// Visual Studio
error C2662: 'void Ali::String::View::swap(Ali::String::View &) noexcept': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Ali::String::View' to 'Ali::String::View &'

// g++
error: passing 'const Ali::String::View' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

If swap doesn't work with constexpr, why have it constexpr?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the question, but are you trying to swap two `constexpr` objects? `constexpr` objects by definition cannot be modified, which swap would do.

Comment: Then why is the swap function marked as constexpr in `std::string_view`? The signature of `std::basic_string_view::swap` in `cppreference.com` is `constexpr void swap(basic_string_view& v) noexcept`. I would like to know why it is `constexpr`.

Comment: That is intriguing. Perhaps you should post *that* as a question.

Comment: Should I delete this question and ask a new one?

Comment: This question isn't bad. I would leave it up and give someone the opportunity to explain why trying to swap `constexpr` objects will not work. It may be useful to other users in the future. You can even answer the question yourself, explaining what led you to the confusion you experienced and how you resolved it.

Comment: Looks like a defect in the specification to me. There's no way it can be invoked as constexpr from outside the class. I think the only place it could be invoked from is a constructor.

Comment: On gcc implementation, this is the signature:  `constexpr void swap(basic_string_view& __sv) noexcept`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`swap` is marked `constexpr` to be allowed to be called in `constexpr` functions, for example:

```
constexpr int foo()
{
    int a = 42;
    int b = 51;

    swap(a, b); // Here swap should be constexpr, else you have error similar to:
                // error: call to non-constexpr function 'void swap(T&, T&) [with T = int]'
    return b;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/848a47acc7bbcf73)

Comment: I tested it right now with my own implementation of string view and it worked perfectly as you said. I still find it a bit non intuitive, sort of a obscure edge case of the language. Thanks :)

Comment: But [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) *shouldn't* be marked as `constexpr` in C++17 and earlier. It's changed in the upcoming C++20 standard. If it is `constexpr` then that's as a compiler-specific extension.