# Why is std::swap allowed in this constexpr function?

Tags: c++, c++17

I wrote a function calculating the gcd of two numbers which uses `std::swap` in the case where the second parameter is greater than the first.

Some time later, I realised that `std::swap` is **not** `constexpr`, but my function still compiled and ran successfully.
I tried with MinGW-w64 8.1.0 and Visual C++ 2017 and it worked for both.

My first thought was that's because `constexpr` functions are allowed to be executed at runtime, so I tried `std::integral_constant<int,gcd(32,12)>`, and it worked.

However, I cannot use any of my own non-constexpr function (which is what I expect).

Here is my test code :

```
#include <utility>

inline void foo() noexcept {
}

template<typename T>
constexpr T gcd(T a, T b) {
    // foo();            // only works with non-constexpr j
    if(a<b) {
        std::swap(a, b); // works for both constexpr i and non-constexpr j
    }
    if(b==0) {
        return a;
    } else {
        return gcd(b, a%b);
    }
}

int main()
{
    constexpr int i = std::integral_constant<int, gcd(32, 12)>::value;
    int j = gcd(32,12);
}
```

So, my question is : why can I use `std::swap` in my function ?

Comment: `swap` is declared as `constexpr`. Take a look at [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap).

Comment: @NutCracker Since C++20, not C++17. I'm not surprised by gcc which muddies the standard boundaries, but VS is usually not lax. Except if you used latest instead of C++17.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46373678/896012

Comment: Look at the header file where `std::swap` is defined. Perhaps it's marked as `constexpr` as a compiler-specific extension?

Comment: My opinion is that the compiler recognizes non-constexpr `swap` function as a function which is callable in a constant-expression because the argument passed is known during translation. That's why you can use `std::swap` in your function. Note that `constexpr` keyword is used only to express your intent. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28821610/5517378). If this answers your question I would be glad to change this comment to an answer.

Comment: @NutCracker that's not how `constexpr` works. Compiler has no power to arbitrary make functions `constexpr` not declared as such. What we have here is an "extension-made-standard".

Comment: the `swap`-branch is never executed. try `gcd(12, 32)` (arguments flipped) and you get the compile error.

Comment: If you change the values passed in to `a < b` you get a [compile error](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Byuly2Pxhcm9b6Yk) with gcc.

Comment: @fdan Indeed, I failed to realise that. I'm surprised the compiler doesn't even warn me about this non-constexpr statement until it actually tries to execute it. I guess you can add this as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a relevant [quote from cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr):

> A constexpr function must satisfy the following requirements:
>
> - ...
> - there exists at least one set of argument values such that an invocation of the function could be an evaluated subexpression of a **core constant expression**

There is a path that does not go through `std::swap()`, where a `a>=b`. In fact, for `gcd(32, 12)` the execution never goes through `std::swap()`.

**EDIT**: I had a look at the [C++14 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf). Section *7.1.5 The constexpr specifier*. Paragraph 5 says:

> For a non-template, non-defaulted constexpr function [...], if no argument values exist such that an invocation of the function or constructor
>   could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant expression (5.20), or, for a constructor, a constant
>   initializer for some object (3.6.2), the program is ill-formed;

and the example they give is:

```
constexpr int f(bool b)
{ return b ? throw 0 : 0; } // OK
```